# Origin and last destination of a customer who has taken multiple flights

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For every customer id, I need to find out the first flight source and last flight destination using spark / pyspark

cid --> customerId

fid --> flight ID -- it is random

Input DataFrame:

| cid | fid | origin | destination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | f12 | texas | newyork |
| 1 | f21 | newyork | delhi |
| 1 | f08 | delhi | japan |

texas -> newyork -> japan

ouput dataframe:

| cid | origin | destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | texas | japan |

I tried doing it with joins but not sure how to merge the resultset after joins to filter only starting flight source and last flight destination

Comment: Thanks @RonakJain. It is helpful. I am thinking of the case when the dataframe is quite large. Isn't collecting of the list (F.collect_list("origin") can slow down the query.

Comment: Performance implication of collect_list is as good as any groupBy operation as we'll be bringing all flights for a customer to one place. If your dataframe is already partitioned that way - there won't be an issue. collect_list is similar to string concatenation, not collectAsList()

Comment: df.groupBy("cid") -- Any aggregation post this will have similar performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** In case the order is not certain:

```
df.groupBy("cid")\
.agg(F.collect_list("origin").alias("origin"), F.collect_list("destination").alias("destination"))\
.select(col("cid"), F.array_except(col("origin"), col("destination")).alias("origin"), F.array_except(col("destination"), col("origin")).alias("destination"))\
.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Essentially, first, collect all origins and destinations as arrays.

[image: IO]

As you can see, the stops (i.e. points except starting point and last destination) will be common in both arrays.

---

If the order can be determined (e.g. using a date column), this would also work:

```
df.groupBy("cid").agg(F.first("origin").alias("origin"), F.last("destination").alias("destination")).show()
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Although this would not work if the order of rows is messed up.

Comment: Does this work just because thr right origin and destination are sorted in the dataframe? what if they are in the wrong order?

Comment: As mentioned, if the dataframe itself is not in order - we would need some column to determine the right order e.g. date -  in that case we'll just add orderBy(date)

Comment: Not necessarily, if the dataframe contains a walk without cycles one can reconstruct it with simple graph theory.

Comment: @Neervana Oh correct, in that case, we can utilize lead/lag. Will update my answer

Comment: @Neervana Updated to handle out-of-order case

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the passenger never takes more than one plane, and that therefore there is a unique path for them to travel

(assuming the start location `start`)

1. Run a query `SELECT * FROM df where origin = start`, that way you get all reachable destinations
2. store the destination in a list
3. run the above query with `start = destinations` for the next step

This will discover the above path.

In case start is not given, you can do something more complex, such as picking a random record, reaching alo destinations as explained above and then also walking back, reaching all sources, you then join these two paths and you have successfully reconstructed the walk.